# variation on the oddtown problem

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

Suppose we have a town with $n$ people who like to form clubs. They form clubs according to the following rules: For any two clubs $C_i,C_j$, $|C_i \cap C_j$| is a multiple of $3$ whenever $i \not = j$. Let $k$ be the number of clubs such that $|C|$ is not divisible by $3$. Show that $k \leq n$.

I assume the proof is similar to that of Oddtown?

Let $l$ be total number of clubs. Define the $l \times n$ matrix $M$ as $M_{ij} = 1$ if the $j^{th}$ person belongs to the $i^{th}$ club, and $0$ otherwise. Associate with each club it's $1 \times n$ characteristic vector $\chi$ where the $i^{th}$ entry of $\chi$ is a $1$ if person $i$ belongs to $C$, and $0$ otherwise. Thus, $M$ is a column vector composed of the $\chi$'s. Then notice that over $\mathbb{F}_3$, $\chi_i \cdot \chi_j = 0$ if $i \not = j$, otherwise it is either $1$ or $2$.
This implies that the vectors are linearly independent. Thus $n \geq rk(M) \geq rk(MM^t) = l \geq k$.

Does this work?

Comment: Is there a question hidden somewhere in this solution?

Comment: I suppose the question would be "is this proof correct?"

Comment: It is roughly correct, but you should explain what part of it you aren't sure about.  If you can't point to a particular section, you probably haven't spent enough time understanding the Oddtown proof.  For instance, it is not true that $n \ge l$, since you've defined $l$ to be the total number of clubs and there could easily be $2^{\lfloor n/3\rfloor}$ clubs with $|C|$ divisible by $3$.

Comment: So where does the argument fall apart then? Is the cause of the problem working with $l$? Let's just look at the $k$ clubs with $|C|$ not divisible by $3$. Then it's certainly true that $\chi_i \cdot \chi_j = 0$ if $ i \not = j$, and otherwise it is either $1$ or $2$, depending on how many townsfolk are a member of $C_i$. 

But then the $k$ characteristic vectors are all linearly independent over ${\mathbb{F}_3}^n$, so does it not immediately follow then that $k \leq n$?